# Raid 1 and Raid 5 with Debian 8 Install

Tags: debian, raid, raid5, raid1, operating-system

Ive been advised that i should install Debian 8 using the following raid configuration:

Raid 1 (2 discs) - for OS
Raid 5 (4 discs) for data.

This way, i can have 2 disc failures and still have a running system.

The question i have is, on the Debian 8 installer, it asks where i want to mount certain directories.

What i need to know is what folders i need to mount on which raid array.

When using guided partitioning, it states that /tmp /var and /home directories should be separate partitions, however what do i need to mount where so that the Raid 1 array contains just the OS and the Raid 5 array contains everything else?

Please advise.

Comment: That depends on _which_ two disks fail. A RAID 5 can tolerate only one disk failure, and if you care about your data you probably don't want to use RAID 5 anyway.

Comment: please advise what i raid i should use?

Comment: RAID 5 is fine, it's just slower when writing. Make a LVM volume group on each of the RAID sets and then use logical volumes to share out the space in each volume group according to what filesystems you want/need. If this is a server I wouldn't bother with a separate /home

Comment: I keep getting told raid 10 would be better for performance. Please advise